# C++ Derived Class Inheritance Method Error

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

It's been a while since I programmed in C++ and I am trying to do some practice problems to get familiar with the syntax again.  I'm writing a program that has a base class `RetailEmployee` with 3 derived classes: `SalesEmployee`, `WarehouseEmployee`, and `ManagerEmployee`.  I have the following code in the top of my header for one of the derived classes:

```
// Sales Employee Class Header
#indef SalesEmployee
#define SalesEmployee

#include <stdio.h>
#include "RetailEmployee.h"

using namespace std;

class SalesEmployee
{
public:
    SalesEmployee(string department, float pay, int ID, string name)
.
.
.
```

However, anytime I try to use a method from the base class on a SalesEmployee instance I get an error saying the method is not found.  Also, all of the files are in the same directory.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: class SalesEmployee : public RetailEmployee { ... } - You need to inherit from the base class. As it is, its just its own class.

Comment: Your ifdef guard shouldn't be `#define SalesEmployee`, it should be something like `#define SALES_EMPLOYEE_H`. Otherwise that's just asking for trouble with the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

You have not instructed the compiler that `class SalesEmployee` is a descendant of `class RetailEmployee`. To do that, you should:

```
class SalesEmployee : public RetailEmployee
{

}
```

You will also need to change your constructor for `class SalesEmployee` to pass along the necessary construction initialization info to `class RetailEmployee`. Such as this in your SalesEmployee.cpp implementation file:

```
SalesEmployee::SalesEmployee(string department, float pay, int ID, string name) : RetailEmployee( department, pay, ID, name ) 
{
    // Whatever special initialization SalesEmployee has goes here.
}
```

I am presuming all those data members are actually defined in the base class since they should be common to all your classes.